# Why does typescript allow variable to be used before declaring it?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript does not give a compiler error for the following code:

```
var b = a + 10; // Why no compilation error here

var a = 10;

alert(b.toString());
```

I would expect the first line to be an error as I have not declared or initialized var a till this time.

If I remove the second line I get the compiler error.

I know its valid in JavaScript but I would expect TypeScript to give me compilation error or warning.

Comment: Because variable declarations are hoisted?

Comment: I have explained why TypeScript *has to* allow it. It is because you might need to do `var x = undefined`

Comment: And In C# an unassigned variable has no meaning. In JavaScript it does. So TypeScript has to allow this.

Comment: I've shown you cases where you actually *need* this "stupid thing". E.g the module pattern. It would be bad if TypeScript took that power of JavaScript away!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you understand that your code is equivalent to:

```
var a, b
b = a + 10
a = 10
alert(b.toString())
```

Which in turn is equivalent to:

```
var a = undefined, b = undefined
b = a + 10
a = 10
alert(b.toString())
```

The reason why it should be allowed is because undefined is a valid value for a variable that you can assign and read.

There are various use cases where this functionality is valuable. E.g The module pattern used in typescript:

```
module x{
    export var foo; 
}
```

Generates javascript code that exploits this fact:

```
var x;
(function (x) {
    x.foo;
})(x || (x = {})); //x was never assigned but used in "x ||" part
```

This is left in TypeScript due to JavaScript backward compatibility (not to mention it is useful).

Here is a purely TypeScript usecase. Perhaps you want to pass undefined into a function call ([this is valid typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=var%20a%3anumber%20=%20undefined;%20//%20same%20as%20simply%20%22var%20a%22%20%0D%0Aconsole.log%28a%29;)):

```
var a:number = undefined; // same as simply "var a" 
console.log(a);
```

It is just assumed that the TypeScript developer wants the power of the underlying JavaScript language.

This is not the case for languages where Reading before Assignment is invalid (e.g C#). In C# an unassigned variable has *no meaning*. In JavaScript it does. So TypeScript *has to* allow this.

Answer (score 11):

Because [hoisting behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15311158/736054) can be confusing. Your code actually means.

```
var a, b

b = a + 10
a = 10

alert(b.toString())
```

There are valid reasons to allow hoisting, but they don't involve `var`, but `function` - you can call function declared later.

```
alert(identity(i))

function identity(i) {
    return i
}
```

In this case, `alert` uses result of function declared later. Thanks to hoisting behavior, it works.

While I agree this case should have an warning (not error, TypeScript wants to be compatible with JavaScript), it doesn't appear that TypeScript currently notices that. Every variable in TypeScript has a type that CANNOT change during lifetime of variable, and in your case, `a` is `number` type (it isn't aware that you use it before assignment, because `var` sets type implicitly). TypeScript assumes it's a number, even if it's not, because of its declaration.

You may want to report this as a bug in TypeScript.

Comment: Its not protecting me. It is allowing me to do that. Which I dont want.

Comment: I'm not so sure about your function example. While it's obvious that `a` references `b`, the body of function is not evaluated until `a` is called. So, this does not have anything to do with hoisting IMO. Here is an example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/fJ9RV/. Although `foo` does not exist at the time of definition and it is not hoisted (because there is no variable declaration), no error is thrown, as long as you call `b` before `a`.