# Function excuted before creation

Tags: javascript

I am no JavaScript expert, but I found some code like this

```
a();

function a(){
  alert('a');
}
```

and I was surprised to find it works (I think something like that will not work in Python). I expected that the function `a` can't be executed before being created. How does interpreter work and why functions can be called before declaration?

Comment: I am no JS expert either, but AFAIK the browser parses the whole document 1st b4 executing it. like reading it 1st and then eval()ing it :D and dont get flaggy on me :D

Comment: read [JavaScript 'hoisting'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311158/javascript-hoisting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because of variable hoisting.
See this answer for more info

[JavaScript 'hoisting'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311158/javascript-hoisting)

Some docs about this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

If you type it like this, it won't work:

```
a();
a = function(){
  alert('a');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Code that is within functions and objects will be run whenever that
>   function or object is called. If it is called from code that is
>   directly in the head or body of the page then its place in the
>   execution order is effectively the spot where the function or object
>   is called from the direct code.

See the [reference here](http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/exeorder.htm).

And in our case the function will give the error as you can see the [example here](http://studiokoi.com/blog/article/execution_order_of_functions_and_variables_in_javascript_and_actionscript).

Answer (score 0):

It's because function a() is declared via Function Declaration syntax, and Function Declaration are executed right after the script is parsed. With other syntax, Function Expression, like this:

```
var b = function(){
  alert('b');
}
```

it won't work ([see example](http://jsbin.com/etahim/1/edit)).

More info: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/