# Is it best to declare temporary variable inside or outside of a loop?

Tags: javascript

What's the best practice, performance-wise, about temporary variables in loops? Is it better to do something like :

```
some_array.forEach(function(item) {
  var temp_obj = {};
  // do some operations with temp_obj
});
```

**OR**

```
var temp_obj;
json.forEach(function(item) {
  temp_obj = {};
  // do some operations with temp_obj
});
```

I always assumed there was no difference in performance, but every time I use it I'm not sure I'm following the good practices...

Comment: @user2356705 that question represents a very different situation.

Comment: IMO, keep the varibles in the nearest scope as possible, so in this case, inside the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two comments are very wrong (at time of writing, some have since been deleted). Since forEach takes a function as an argument, a closure is formed and variable hoisting doesn't apply.

To answer your question: depends on the context. You shouldn't use global variables, but if your code from the second example is wrapped inside some other function, it's preferable, since the variable is only allocated once (incidentally, number 2 illustrates the concept of closures well, if wrapped inside a parent function).

Comment: Why is *"since the variable is only initialized once"* preferable?

Comment: _"only initialized once"_ -- do you mean _"only allocated once"_? It's set every time the assignment is evaluated.

Comment: @Ted Hopp You're completely right - I was being sloppy. Corrected in my answer. If the object had some actual content/was significant size-wise, then it would have to be initialized every time, but since it's blank, it only gets allocated.

Comment: @BlueSkies The computer has to put aside some memory in a register for each object. The fewer times, the better

Comment: To be honest, to quote Crockford, it's all 'lost in the noise'. My answer is only really applicable if the object is fairly large.

Answer (score 2):

Depends of what kind of performance we are talking about. In any case I doubt any of those will show a noticeable difference. Also keep in mind that the engine might apply optimizations and the generated might actually differ.

---

```
some_array.forEach(function(item) {
  var temp_obj = {};
  // do some operations with temp_obj
});
```

In this case the variable `temp_obj` will be faster to look up because it is defined in local scope. This is probably preferable.

---

```
var temp_obj;
json.forEach(function(item) {
  temp_obj = {};
  // do some operations with temp_obj
});
```

Creation time of the function might be less because a local variable doesn't have to be created.

---

And of course there is also a behavioral difference between local variables and free variables. Free variables will be "shared" between each function call.

Answer (score 1):

There are no good practices it all depends on the scope you are trying to achieve.

Inside the loop means your var will not be accessible outside the loop. There are also a few other things to get in relation with closure.  one [resource](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/) for instance

Answer (score 0):

This is actually interesting question, mainly because of the way that javascript handles scoping. There are a couple of comments that mention that this question has been answered previously, but it doesn't appear to me that it has. Note that there is a big difference between this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++){}
```

and this:

```
someArray.forEach(function(item){});
```

because of the fact that the callback in the second one provides scope. If you are using a for loop, it literally doesn't matter if you declare the variable inside or outside of the function because the variable will be [hoisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311158/javascript-hoisting/15313200#15313200) up out of the loop anyway.

In the case that you are specifically asking about, whether or not to declare the variable inside or outside of the function matters because the function provides scope, and the variable will not be hoisted. If you care about performance, you should declare it outside of the callback, since the variable will only be created once. If you do not need to use the variable outside of the callback, however, I would actually recommend defining the variable within the callback. In my opinion, it makes the code easier to read and unless your temp object is very memory expensive, it won't effect performance in any noticeable way.

Comment: *"unless your temp object is very memory expensive, it won't effect performance in any noticeable way"* From the example it looks like the object is actually created inside the loop, no matter where the variables is defined. Are you saying that assigning an large object to a local variable is less performant than assigning it to a variable in a higher scope?

Comment: @FelixKling - That's a really good point that I totally missed. In the case like the OP posted, there still isn't any difference because allocation always happens in the loop. The case I meant was when you allocate the object before the call to forEach, and then just use it in the callback. The only way the code will be more performant is if the temp object is memory expensive, and only ever defined once.