# Javascript Error when using undefined variable

Tags: javascript

Check this interactive Google Chrome console log:

```
test_1 = 'ok'
 > "ok"

test_2 = test_2 || 'ok'
 > ReferenceError: test_2 is not defined

var test_3 = test_3 || 'ok'
 > undefined

test_1
 > "ok"

test_2
 > ReferenceError: test_2 is not defined

test_3
 > "ok"
```

When I call `test_1 = 'ok'` I leave out the `var` constructor, but the browser still understands this. I assume it fills in with the `var` where I omitted, just like it fills in with semicolons.

But for `test_2 = test_2 || 'ok'` I get an error. I know `test_2` is not defined but it doesn't keep my next example `test_3` from working. For some reason the missing `var` statement becomes a problem.

Can somebody explain to me why the interpreter throws an error there?

Comment: [JavaScript 'hoisting'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311158/javascript-hoisting) also look at [JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

Comment: You can omit `var`, it implies your variable is global.

Comment: I don't understand why you downvote this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, hoisting.

Take the third example, that "works":

```
var test_3 = test_3 || 'ok'
```

What JavaScript actually does is the following:

```
var test_3;

test_3 = test_3 || 'ok';
```

Now that `test_3` is declared, referring to `test_3` simply returns `undefined` rather than throwing a `ReferenceError`, so what you're essentially doing is this:

```
var test_3;

test_3 = undefined || 'ok';
```

This isn't true with the second example, as `test_2` is never declared.

Comment: "This isn't true with the second example, as `test_2` is never defined." You mean it's never declared.