# Javascript functions parsing order

Tags: javascript, parsing

Can someone please explain in great detail why in the following function, the return value is 1.5? Does javascript parse bottom to top or there is more to it?

```
    (function f() {
        function f() { return 1; }
        return f();
        function f() { return 2; }
        function f() { return 1.5; }
    })();
```

Comment: This behavior is called **hoisting**. Google it!

Comment: One I learn answer added an example back in time read may be you find helpful [JavaScript 'hoisting'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311158/javascript-hoisting/15313200#15313200)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions are '[hoisted](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)' to the top of the scope they live in.

So your code actually reads:

```
(function f() {
    function f() { return 1; }
    function f() { return 2; }
    function f() { return 1.5; }
    return f();
})();
```

QED:

```
(function f() {
    function f() { return 1; }
    return f();
    function f() { return 1.5; }
    function f() { return 2; }
})(); //=> 2
```

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan that's ok, I'm not primarily in it for the votes ;)

Comment: @kooilnc then add some theory, defined what is hosting.. I feel it is incomplete if someone new to it....

Comment: That's why I added a link (http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html). To keep the answer short, and because Ben Cherry explains it pretty good.

Comment: @kooilnc Thanks Kooilnc,, I didn't read it (as I am not web-dev) I will read it ...

Comment: I saw the link I agree... thanks! btw I pick a [book](http://www.amazon.in/JavaScript-jQuery-The-missing-Manual/dp/9350235625?tag=googinhydr17902-21) today  I read first-1 chapter feel it is good.. do you have any suggestion.

Comment: A lot of scripting I learned by ... scripting and trying to answer questions @SO. There are excellent online sources for free to learn more, like http://eloquentjavascript.net/print.html or http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery. I have tried reading books on programming, but most of the time they bore me or I end up  (re)coding the examples before I finish the book and forget about it.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, JS interpreter first looks at all declarations and then the rest of the code. Correct?

Comment: @KooiInc Thanks Kooilnc I like fist [link very](http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html) much... and downloaded HTML-zip. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/54NQ8/)***

As a result of hoisting, this is equivalent to

```
(function f(){
 var f;
 f = function(){ return 1; };
 f = function(){ return 2; };
 f = function(){ return 1.5; };
 return f();
})();
```

Hoisting can be tricky, as there are two aspects of it occurring here. First, the variable definition is hoisted

> Every definition of a variable is really a declaration of the variable at the top of its scope and an assignment at the place where the definition is.<sup>1</sup>

Next, each function initialization is hoisted

> Functions initializations happen at the top of the parent function (above vars). Since vars declarations with names already existent as a parameter or a function are no-ops, we get some surprising results.<sup>1</sup>

<sub>1: **[Scope Cheatsheet <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet)**</sub>

Comment: actually both of you don't defined what is called 'hoisting' ?? but + because I got it.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - Please see edits for additional information on hoisting.

Answer (score 1):

when js interprer comes to the function first it looks for all var and function constructions (but not anonymous functions ) and atirs them in the order it has found them, after this it starts to execute code from start of the function. in your case f function which returns 1.5 is the last, so it pverides the previos 2 f functios