# Alert is not displaying as expected.!

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just tried to check the scope variation by using the following code, but the result is coming not in an expected way. Can anyone explain what's going on exactly behind this..?

```js
var a = 10;

+ function () {
  a = 5;
  var a;
  alert("inline  " + a); //Expected undefined but it displayed as 5
}();

alert(a); //Expected 5 but it alerted 10
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3rCYz/3/)

Comment: That is because `a` is only declared

Comment: Read about "hoisting".

Comment: @RPM yeah.. but this confuses me.. http://jsfiddle.net/3rCYz/4/

Comment: Are you trying to hack the compiler?

Comment: the a is defined in the scope of that function there.

Comment: Javascript function only have local and global scope. Anything (variable/method) which is declared inside a function/method has local scope. And variable which is declared outside the function/method has global scope.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript 'hoisting'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311158/javascript-hoisting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**var hoisting**

> Because variable declarations (and declarations in general) are
>   processed before any code is executed, declaring a variable anywhere
>   in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top. This also means
>   that a variable can appear to be used before it's declare

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

The compiler understands your code as

```
var a;
a = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

The position of a `var` declaration within a function doesn't matter. These are entirely equivalent:

```
function () {
    var a;
    a = 5;
}

function () {
    a = 5;
    var a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when use "var a" you request global value of variable, use "window.a" to display it:

```
<script>
var a = 10;

+ function () {
    a = 5;
    var a;
    alert("inline  " + window.a); //Expected undefined but it displayed as 5
}();

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = 10; // Global scope

+ function () {
    a = 5; // You are not using Var here .. so it is also a global scope
    var a; // Now you are mentioning your a is Var so scope is changed from global to this function
    alert("inline  " + a); // Printing 5 because you local scope a has value of 5.
}();

alert(a); // Printing 10 because of global scope a has value 10
```