# Why javascript doesn't look up global scope in second case

Tags: javascript

foo will lookup b value with 2 as expected when executing in console

```
function foo() {
    console.log(b)
}
var b = 2
foo() // 2 for console.log
```

but when I do this

```
function foo() {
    console.log(b)
    var b = 2
    console.log(b)
}
var b = 2
foo() // undefined for first console.log
```

it won't lookup b in global scope anymore why ?

Comment: Funny that regardless of how often such questions are answered, posters would rather answer the question (or post a comment…) than search for a suitable answer and close it as a duplicate.

Comment: I marked a poor duplicate, there's a better one here if someone else wants to close this: [*JavaScript 'hoisting'*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311158/javascript-hoisting).

Comment: The direct answer to the question is: Because it's shadowed by b in the local scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because of what is called Javascript Hoisting, this is how javascript sees your code:

```
function foo() {
  var b; // javascript hoisted this variable on top
  console.log(b) // so here you see underfined
  b = 2;
  console.log(b);
}
```

Now because javascript hoised variable `b` on top of function, your global variable `b` was never used and hence statement immendiately after hoisted variable showed `undefined`. So if you remove new declaration (`var` keyword) from your function, you should still have access to global `b` variable.

BTW, it is good practice to declare all your variables on top of function like:

```
function foo() {
  var b = 2;
  console.log(b);
}
```

---

To know more on the topic, see this:

- http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: "Hoisting" is jargon, and misleading to me. What actually happens is that variable declarations are processed after the entire program is parsed but before any code is executed. But yeah, "hoisting" seems to be the popular term for that.