# What is the explanation for the answers to these javascript interview questions?

Tags: javascript

Could some one help me in explaining the below snippets. These were asked during my interview. Please post answers with reasoning.

[image]

Comment: I found this tool extremely helpful in certain cases: http://www.pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=edit

It visualizes the execution order and shows the at the moment results to the right

Answer (score 2):

The first example is pretty straightforward. The `employeeId` is defined outside `foo function`, the `foo function` is being called, a new value is being assigned to `employeeId`, returns from the `foo function` and it prints the value.

The tricky part in the second example is the `function employeeId(){}` within the `function foo()`. When the code executes and you are in the `function foo`, the `function employeeId` will be defined/hoisted. You can think it like you are creating a variable `employeeId` and that you assigned a function there. Because of that, when the code actually executes, it will use this `function employeeId` that got defined/hoisted and it will override it with the value '123bcd'. In this way, the employeeId of the outer scope remains untouched.

**Edit 1:** While I was searching for providing extra resources, here is a question about hoisting and about the same problem that you've posted: [JavaScript 'hoisting'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311158/javascript-hoisting)